# Mac OS X Network Issue

Tags: macos, networking, mac

I have a OS X Server application that is running on one of my servers.

It has Chat enabled and it works just fine, but it disconnects me and other clients often.

I assume that the issue comes from the network, but I can't be sure until I test it.

Any ideas for an application that give me a report of network crashes?

Beside that I am willing for any advices.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) did a great job on that network issue.